# How to set different custom claims based on where user signs up?

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 sign up pages, one for students and one for teachers.
How can I set a different custom claim for each when they sign up? (student: true OR teacher:true)

I am guessing it could be possible at .onCreate? I can set just one custom claim per onCreate function, how to make this dynamic?

```
exports.AddTeacherRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (authUser) => {
if (authUser.email) {
  const customClaims = {
    teacher: true,
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `authUser` Object passed to Authentication Cloud Functions is exactly the same type of Object than the [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html) that is returned by the Firebase Admin SDK.

Depending on how you created the user (e.g. from the front-end, with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` in JavaScript or e.g. from the Admin SDK, with [`createUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#createuser)) the `UserRecord` may hold more or less "extra" properties (e.g. `displayName`, `photoURL`, etc).

The problem is that there is no specific property of this `UserRecord` instance that you could use to indicate the role of the user (student or teacher). Therefore you cannot get this information in your Cloud Function, which is triggered when the user is created.

A common approach is to add this kind of extra data to a Firestore document (or a Realtime Database node) which has the same id than the user Id. Then from this document, you could trigger a Cloud Function that updates the user record.

Another approach is to use a Cloud Function that does all the job: create the user, set the custom claim and create a Firestore document. You will find in the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) some detailed explanations about this kind of approach.

---

To answer the question you asked in the deleted answer:

> Just to verify, it could be solved by creating 2 separate https
> callable cloud functions that handle the sign up for each role for
> example?

Yes you could have two callable Cloud Functions, but I think it should be possible to just have one and pass different parameter values when calling this Cloud Function, depending on the user role.

Something like:

```
const setCustomClaim = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('setCustomClaim');

const userRole = "student" // or role = "teacher"
 
setCustomClaim({role: userRole, userId, bar: "foo" }).then(function(result) {
  // Read result of the Cloud Function.
  // ...
});
```